# How do I turn off the chat for a specific player?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am making a plugin where people can toggle the chat for themselves on the server.

What I have right now works pretty well:

```
@EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGHEST)
public void onPlayerChat(@NotNull AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {
    if(TOGGLED_USERS_BY_UUID.contains(e.getPlayer().getUniqueId().toString())) {
        e.setCancelled(true);
        e.getPlayer().sendRawMessage(ToggleChat.LANG.get("cannotChat"));
        return;
    }
    String message = e.getMessage();
    getLogger().info(String.format("<%s>: %s", e.getPlayer().getName(), message));
    e.setCancelled(true);
    for(Player p : getServer().getOnlinePlayers()) {
        if(!TOGGLED_USERS_BY_UUID.contains(p.getUniqueId().toString()))
            p.sendRawMessage(String.format("<%s> %s", e.getPlayer().getName(), message));
    }
}
```

But the problem comes when users have other things for their chat, such as a specific level for their chat message like `(lvl) [username] - message` or something.

How do I make it so that I don't have to re-send the message to users or just cancel the event for a specific user?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. I don't know what you did either

2. What do you mean by re-send the chat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event) {
    event.getRecipients().remove(/*player who shouldn't see chat*/);
}
```

If you want to filter players by their xp levels, you can use

```
getRecipients().removeIf(p -> p.getLevel() < minimumLevel)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation

Comment: Javadoc should be pretty straightforward:

Comment: org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent
@NotNull  public Set <Player> getRecipients()


Gets a set of recipients that this chat message will be displayed to.
The set returned is not guaranteed to be mutable and may auto-populate on access. Any listener accessing the returned set should be aware that it may reduce performance for a lazy set implementation.
Listeners should be aware that modifying the list may throw UnsupportedOperationException if the event caller provides an unmodifiable set.


Returns:
All Players who will see this chat message

Comment: Although there is no guarantee the set is mutable, I think this is the only solution without cancelling the event and sending a new message (which OP didn't want); at least without packets

Comment: This is straightforward.  The javadoc for spigot is not easy to read and does not include this method.  Thank you for explaining, I'll accept the answer after I test it :)